# Export only the selected object to STL file in Blender 2.8x

Tags: export, stl

How can I export only the selected objects out to an STL file.  I tried hiding from view and render but they are still included in the STL ile see images below.

## My settings before exporting to STL format.

[image]

## The image when it's imported

[image: image2]

PS: I'm using Blender 2.83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select the object you want exported, then begin the export process as normal, by going to *File* > *Export* > *Stl*, then under the **Include** section, you will see a checkbox for exporting only the selection.

[image]